# That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers When Using AutoCompleteBox in DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: xbap, autocompletebox

I Develope a XBAP Partial trust that use datagrid.
This DataGrid has a TemplateColumn that use AutoComplateBox as Editing Element.
When Click on One of that Column's cell throw the exception

```
System.Security.SecurityException: That assembly does not allow partially trusted callers.
```

any idea?
tanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem solved in Visual Studio 2010 and can use it without any exception